# Kotlin, как получить значения параметров в аннотации?

Tags: рефлексия, kotlin

Создал в Kotlin аннотацию для поля класса, аннотация принимает в качестве параметра строку, но не могу понять как при помощи reflection прочитать значение параметра аннотации на этом поле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
annotation class Description(val value: String)

class Test {

    @field:Description(value="My field")
    var myfield: String? = null

    fun getMyFieldDescription(): String {

        return this.javaClass.getDeclaredField("myfield")
                   .getAnnotation(Description::class.java)
                   .value
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    var test = Test()

    println(test.getMyFieldDescription())
}
```

[kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin)